# How to remove the blank space before the supercite number?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm currently writing my thesis in LaTeX, and I have a small issue: I'm using "supercite" command, but there is a blank space between the ponctuation and the superscript number that I'd like to remove. It doesn't appear with other kind of citation, like "footfullcite". If anybody has a solution, I'd be glad!

I would like the "supercite" command to give something citation "1" in my example, instead of what it currently gives, the citation "2".[image]

Thank you in advance,

Gwen

Edit: here's the code that I used for this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{a4wide}
    \usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fltpoint}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=nature, sorting=none, date=year]{biblatex} 
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{subscript}  
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \setlength{\intextsep}{20pt}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{20pt} 


\usepackage{fnpct} 
\AdaptNoteOpt\footfullcite\multfootcite 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{giveninits=true, isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, uniquename=init} 
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}\makeatother 

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{title}%
    \clearfield{publisher}%
}{}
} 



\addbibresource{library.bib}


\begin{document}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footfullcite{Liu1999} Donec cursus erat neque, ac laoreet tortor venenatis eu. Ut lobortis rhoncus.\supercite{Rong2017}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have provided no example so it is hard to help but you will have added the space somewhere in your source, so the answer will be do not add the space, put the cite command immediately after the text, but with no code shown it is hard to correct the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no the issue is that I don't (or not in an obvious way at least). Here's the code :

Comment: Please edit your question so that it has a complete small document that shows the problem, you can use the `{}` button in the site editor to mark a code block.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I edited my post with the code.

Answer (score 3):

Very common problem. You're adding spaces at every article:

```latex
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{%<--- 
    \clearfield{title}%
    \clearfield{publisher}%
  }{}%<---
}
```

[image]

By the way, `a4wide` is deprecated and should not be used. Use `geometry` instead, with its easily settable parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ok, that's noted for a4wide, I'll use that then.

Comment: Thanks. This has been bugging me for a while. Now finally resolved.